# Handle Unicode in oracle throgh standart interface .net or dapper

Tags: .net, oracle

I use dapper library with oracle and it relay on abstract  .net interfaces IDBCommand IDBPrameter.
Seems both implementations have of oracle libraries (maaged and unmanaged) have same issue.
Here is example from Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client library
[image]
As you can see it maps DBType.String into varchar, but should map into nvarchar2 !
This case the problem that I am not able to insert unicode characters.

do you have any suggestion how to deal with it ?

Comment: What is your database character set?  Oracle has been suggesting that new database installs use Unicode for the database character set for a rather long time.

Comment: What is the reason for using `NVARCHAR2`? It mainly exist for historical reasons, nowadays there is no good argument to use it anymore.

Comment: guys you asking weird questions, the problem not in database. It insert fine using N'' syntax. Not use Nvarchar ? and what other option ? yellow line which use native nvarchar type works.